# thephpleague/glide: how to create own manipulator?

Tags: php, image-processing, php-glide

I am using [Glide](https://github.com/thephpleague/glide) for image manipulation. But default manipulation Api methods are not enough for me. For example, I need the [border api](http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/api/border/) to support different top/bottom and left/right border widths.

I read through all the [docs](http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/advanced-usage/), but I can't see how do I create my own or extend existing manipulators?

Comment: Well this will be an abstract comment but [the advanced usage guide](http://glide.thephpleague.com/1.0/config/advanced-usage/) mentions a method `setApi(ApiInterface $api)` which to me says you can extend their default `ApiInterface` implementation and add whatever you need to it.

Comment: @apokryfos Honestly speaking, I see I can use own api or replace server factory. But doing this I meet issues here and there, and need to reverse engeneer the code. I would love to find complete instruction how to add my own manipulator.

Comment: There does not seem to be a native way to do this. Perhaps if you actually try to extend (not replace) the built-in Api and you are encountering issues you can ask specific questions about those issues or maybe make a feature request to the glide dev team